# Can I get the Firefox 4 button icons from Windows XP to display in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, icons, windows-xp

The Firefox 4 icons that display in Windows XP (e.g., back button, refresh button, home button) are really nice. Is there a way to get these icons and use them in my Ubuntu Firefox 4 installation?

The Firefox 4 icons used in Windows XP:  http://img707.imageshack.us/i/firefox4iconsfromwindow.jpg/

Answer (score 3):

Install the theme [Strata RELOADED](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/strata-reloaded/) from the Mozilla addons repository. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the image posted, but I suppose you want something like the Strata theme:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7749/